# "i += 1" vs. "i = i + 1" time and performance

Tags: python, performance, time, execution

The execution times for `i += 1` and `i = i + 1` are different. For example, given the following snippet:

```
snip = """
x = 0
for i in range(10000):
    x += i
"""

snip2 = """x=0
for i in range(10000):
    x = x + i
"""
```

First run it once:

```
print timeit.timeit(snip, number=1)
print timeit.timeit(snip2, number=1)
0.000745058059692
0.000648021697998
```

and `x = x + i` is faster than `x += i`, run it a thousand times:

```
print timeit.timeit(snip, number=1000)
print timeit.timeit(snip2, number=1000)

0.663557052612
0.661299943924
```

then both result in nearly the same time, off by few microseconds, and run it a million times:

```
print timeit.timeit(snip, number=1000000)
print timeit.timeit(snip2, number=1000000)
771.912870884
778.865171909
```

then it clearly results in the opposite of case one; `x += i` is cheaper now and the other is way costlier.

What is the difference in execution of those two statements? What is Big O time for both?

This question originates from a situation where my server has statements `i += 1` and billions of DB transactions will end in dead lock, but with `i = i + 1` it works great.

Comment: Note that *"Big O time"* is exactly what you're **not** looking at here - simple arithmetic operations are `O(1)`!

Comment: Are your results replicable? is `x+= 1` faster by seven seconds 10 times out of ten?

Comment: Whether your code is open to deadlocks is around semantic differences, not performance ones. `__add__` and `__iadd__` aren't the same thing.

Comment: Micro-benchmarks are notoriously unreliable. How many times have you run this? Did you restart the interpretter between invokations? Did you have a warm up period?

Comment: These are two different lines are code where any difference in performance would be miniscule and not worth worrying about. Go for what you find more readable and manageable

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure changing `i += 1` to `i = i + 1` is **not** a correct fix for your dead lock. I mean: there is an other issue and you are just happening to avoid the problem. But at the next code change it could come up again.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, ...if this is CPython, there's no JIT, so I'm not entirely sure that a warm-up period and a fresh start are relevant. (For Jython or PyPi it'd be a whole different story).

Comment: @Bakuriu: May be that was quick fix and that leaded me to this question. thanks for pointing though

Comment: @Andrew: yeah I tried searching ir but didn't found that some how, but that perfect thanks, I have also flaged the question too duplicate and close it.

Comment: @Sayse why not to worry about it, if it can make considerable difference on your execution time, I can try to find the root of it and see what can be better for code. thanks though

Comment: @shodowsjedi there will always be other parts of your code where you can gain greater performance increases